# Unexpected 302 Redirects in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I locally designed my site. Then exported MySql database as Sql file and executed the scripts in the real server. Also copied the joomla directory to the server.

Now, I am getting strange 302 redirection errors in my web site, when I am accessing the home page. However, I am able to login into the admin panel. I can see all my contents available.

The redirection happens to the same page, i.e. continuous requests are issued to the index.php/en/ (checked using fiddler).

Am I missing any configurations?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Well this is tricky without a link to the site to see the behaviour in person, but it could be that you forgot to upload a .htaccess file or set the Redirect Base or cookie path/domain in the configuration.php (if it's empty then it's probably not a problem, only if you have manually edited it).